# How to bind data attributes in Sitecore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

**Desired output**

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown">Countries <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
```

**View:**

```
  @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Target URL", item.Item, new { @data_toggle = "dropdown" })
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  @Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

**Rendered html:**

```
<a href="#" data_toggle="dropdown">Countries <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
```

1. `href` is generated. It is not needed.
2. The `data-toggle` attribute isn't set.

Comment: What's wrong with `<a data-toggle="dropdown">@item.Item<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>`?

Comment: @qwerty Have you seen http://brad-christie.com/blog/2014/09/24/using-data-attributes-with-sitecore-mvc/ ?

Comment: @MarekMusielak. Yes.Been there. Where to create the `Process(RenderFieldArgs args)`? Should I create a new config file?If yes, then how to register it. Hard to figure all this for a beginner.

Comment: @Liam. But would that make the field editable?

Comment: Do you mean in the experience editor? Also are you using Glass mapper at all?

Comment: Yes. In the experience editor. Not using Glass mapper

Comment: You are going to need to use an edit frame or check to see if the user is in edit mode. When in display, show the answer above using @item.Item. When in edit, show a normal HyperLink field. Like you saw over on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170844/how-to-include-html-inside-anchor-tag-in-sitecore

Answer (score 0):

An edit frame or edit-mode check are possible solutions, but you could also create your own extension to the HtmlHelper from Sitecore. Just to give you an idea:

```
public static HtmlString Test(this SitecoreHelper helper, string fieldName, Item item, object parameters)
{
    var result = helper.BeginField(fieldName, item, parameters);
    return new HtmlString(result.ToString().Replace("href=\"#\" ", string.Empty));
}
```

This quick example will remove the href="#" but you can make it more intelligent.

In your View you can use:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Test("Target URL", item.Item, new { @data_toggle = "dropdown" })
<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>;
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Just some quick test code but it should work already and can be extended to get you what you need.